# jquery default context

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to load a page (with js, css) into a DIV within the same document and javascript in loaded page mustn't apply on parent page content. Is it possible to set something like default context on the loaded page? see the basic example bellow

parent page:

```
<h1>normal</h1>
<span class="externalpage">data</span>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/Index",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".externalpage").html(data);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

/ajax/Index "subpage" - I'm not alowed to change content of this page.

```
<h1>ajax</h1>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("h1").text("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Would it be a problem if the loaded scripts didn't run at all?

Comment: yes, it would. basically i'd like to do something like an iframe. subpage

Comment: Interesting. It *might* be possible, but it will probably be ugly. I'll try to put a fiddle together. Out of curiosity, is something preventing you from using an `<iframe>`? It would be the easiest way.

Comment: UFRAME http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/uframe.aspx this is pretty much what I am looking for. 
however this solution  is based on htmlparser.js http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/  and it's not bulletproof. it fails e.g. on pages with <!DOCTYPE html> , or pages with templates for $.tmpl.

Comment: Looks like it's possible after all. I'd love to hear if my solution still works when `$.tmpl()` comes into play, though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, you want the loaded scripts to execute in some kind of "partial" document context, limited to the contents of your `externalpage` element (i.e. only the loaded `<h1>` element must change, not the one outside the `<div>`).

That can be achieved by temporarily overriding `$.find()` (not [$.fn.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/), which is not the same thing), and substituting the `externalpage` element in the `context` argument if it is unspecified or equal to the document itself:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/Index",
        success: function(data) {
            var $root = $(".externalpage");
            var realFind = $.find;
            $.find = function(query, context, extra, seed) {
                return realFind.apply(this, [
                    query,
                    context && context !== document ? context : $root[0],
                    extra,
                    seed
                ]);
            };
            $root.html(data);
            $.find = realFind;
        }
    });
})
```

jsFiddle features an echo service that I could use to test this solution. You can see the results [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fhamidi/mcWPk/).

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be a way to set a default context easily in jQuery. You can, however, work around that by caching the context, and just calling `.find()` from it:

```
var $c = $('.externalpage');
$c.find('h1').text('xxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

It's a bit unwieldy, and you have to change the way you code though.

Alternatively, you can just encapsulate it within a function:

```
var $j = function(a) {
    return $(a, '.externalpage');
};

// and then you can use that like
$j('h1').text('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');

// if you want to revert to the global jQuery object, just use $ instead of $j
```

Answer (score 2):

This is crude but should work. It copies jQuery to another variable and then replaces `$` with a custom function; hence you can make it do what you want.

```
var $copy = $; // Original jQuery

$ = function() {
    if(!(this instanceof $)) return new $();
}; // fake jQuery function

$.prototype.ready = function(f) {
    f(); // fake ready, just execute function directly
}

$.prototype.text = function(t) {
    $copy(".externalpage h1").text(t); // set only the correct h1 to the text
}
```

Now, in the fetched file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("h1").text("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
})
```

what will happen is it will execute the fake jQuery functions, which as defined above should work as you want.

You would have to use `$copy` for the real jQuery functions in your own file though.

Comment: I was trying to get my answer to work using prototype as well, but stopped short. Good work :D One question though; with the `.text()` prototype, wouldn't that change `.externalpage h1` every single time, no matter what I select with the new `$` object? e.g. if I go `$('h2').text('xxxxxx')`, wouldn't that still change the `h1` instead?

Comment: @richardneililagan: Yes, you're completely correct. This isn't a full-fledged solution. In fact you'd need to create a specialized hacked version of jQuery depending on the page you are fetching. E.g. now only `.text` and `.ready` are available anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Because the subpage is loaded into the main document and loads the document context, you can't change the context that the subpage uses in any way that doesn't require changing the subpage.

Some possible workarounds:

1. If the subpage is a complete page, load it into an iFrame.
2. Kill the loaded scripts completely:

   ```
   $.ajax ( {
       url:        "/ajax/Index",
       success:    function (data) {
           var safePage    = $(data).find ("script"). Remove ();
           safePage.appendTo ".externalpage");
       }
   } );
   ```
3. Load 2 copies of jQuery, only the second one is one you hacked for this purpose.  Maybe like:

   ```
   <script> 
       $.noConflict ();

       jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
           $.ajax({
               url: "/ajax/Index",
               success: function (data) {
                   $(".externalpage").html(data);
               }
           });
       })
   </script>
   <!-- This next copy of jQuery only operates on the externalpage div -->
   <script src="Your hacked version of jquery" ...
   ```