# Create new jQuery global object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think that the title would be a little confusing, but, what I want, is to create a new jQuery object `$()`, with a specific context.

For example, I have my jQuery object whose context is the `window` object. And, I want to create a new jQuery object, with a new context wich would be a specific `div`. The global jQuery, and the new jQuery, would have different context, so, I think, the jQuery for the div, wouldn't have access to external HTML elements, outside that div.

The problem is, that I don't know how to create a new jQuery object. I was reading the jQuery source code, but is a little bit confusing, and I don't sure how to create a new jQuery object with an specific context. How could I do it?

Thank's advance!

Comment: why do you want to do that? Are you looking for something like $(selector[, context])[http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1]

Comment: I think you're approaching your bigger problem the wrong way.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Create a new jQuery object with a smaller context that the global jQuery, if because I want that, for example, the jQuery object from de div, couldn't access to external elements.

Comment: I want that because the jQuery from the div, would be an external jQuery, and I don't want that code to access to external elements

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7055993/464709

Comment: This is an [XY Problem.  The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.  That is, you are trying to solve problem `X`, and you think solution `Y` would work, but instead of asking about `X` when you run into trouble, you ask about `Y`.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  Y in this case being a Context for jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I have understood your correctly. Does it help -

```
var $new = $("#your-div-id");

//always use new jQuery object $new for your purpose
$new.find(selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand how jQuery works here. jQuery wraps a selector statement like `div#some-id-here`, looks it up and then tries to run the chained operations on it. The default `$` doesn't really have a context in the sense you are think of.

Here's an example assuming two divs with ids `one` and `two` respectively.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').find('div').each(function(i) {
       alert($(this).attr('id')); 
    });
});
```

Will work.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.find('div').each(function(i) {
       alert($(this).attr('id')); 
    });
});
```

Will not work because `$` does not really have a `window` context like you think it does. The "context" it has is whatever you tell it to select.

Comment: And how can I tell jQuery which context should have?